# Switching computers with a persistent usb

Tags: boot, kernel, live-usb, persistence

I am trying to create a USB Drive to run the OS on several different computers, without installing anything to the computers themselves. I used pen drive Linux to create a bootable Live USB and have 4 GB persistence option enabled. Tested persistence by running Ubuntu on a mac book pro, switch screen saver and then booted Apple OS, back to Ubuntu. Worked well and settings saved. I powered down the computer, unplugged the USB and was confronted by kernel panic the next time I booted from the USB. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.